# What version of Destiny do I have (Ps4)?

Tags: psn, ps4, destiny, version-differences

I bought the PS4 White Bundle with destiny (http://www.gamestop.com/ps4/consoles/playstation-4-white-destiny-hardware-bundle/115475)  a month ago. I turned on my new PlayStation 4, and popped in the disc. The disc itself only said "destiny ". No guardian edition, no ghosts edition, none of that. When I played the game today, I noticed down in the "What's New" section, it said that "Younesis32 played Destiny: Digital Guardian edition 3 times." What? Which version of Destiny do I *actually* have? And if I *actually* have the Digital Guardian Edition, where is my Expansion pass? Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: Also, do you think I got ripped off? In the Destiny game case, I got a vanguard armory code that expired a month before I bought the system.

Comment: As a side note, the vanguard armory code is a novelty - some might say useless. You will have better things than those very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

**You did not get ripped of. You got what you paid for.**

From what I could tell, I found that in the bundled items it displays:

- PlayStation®4 System (Glacier White)
- DualShock®4 Wireless Controller (Glacier White)
- **Destiny Video Game (Physical Disc)**
- 30-Day PlayStation Plus Trial
- HDMI Cable
- Power Cable
- Wired Mono Headset
- USB Charging Cable

I could not find any mention of the "Digital Guardian Edition" so they are not entitled to give you the additional expansion pack.

You may have received the disc for the expansion pack version, and the armory code (although expired), you did not buy the Digital Guardian Edition so your not entitled to anything extra.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the "What's New" section. It said I played the digital guardian edition. smh.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you get with the Digital Guardian Edition of Destiny: Digital Download of Destiny, Early Access to the Vanguard Armory and Player Emblem pre-order bonus, Exclusive In-Game: Ghost Casing, Player Ship and Player Emblem. This also includes the Expansion Pass.

It seems like you received the standard physical copy of Destiny, plus an already expired Vanguard Armory code. You do not have the Digital Guardian Edition.

Here is the link to the official website - http://www.destinythegame.com/wheretobuy/editions